# TcpListener Freezing on Reconnect

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I am using a TcpListener to receive messages. One of our clients is having an issue where the listener occasionally will not reconnect after receiving a message. My reconnect code is pretty basic, and straight from the TcpListener API.

```
tcpClientConnected = new ManualResetEvent(false);
server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
server.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
server.Start();

while (isListening)
{
    Parent.Log("******************** WAITING FOR A MESSAGE ********************", Verbose.Debug);
    tcpClientConnected.Reset();
    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(AcceptMessage), server);
    tcpClientConnected.WaitOne();   //  Wait for an incoming message
    if(isListening)
        Parent.Log("******************** CONNECTION RESET ********************", Verbose.Debug);
    else
        Parent.Log("******************** LISTENER DISCONNECTED ********************", Verbose.Debug);
}
```

Because of logging, I know that `tcpClientConnected.Set()` gets called. IsListening is still true, and the code loops back to BeginAcceptTcpClient. The first line of code in AcceptMessage writes to the log, and this is never hit. Therefore, I know that a new message is never received, and the server locks.

This customer can run for several days successfully, and then lock up. This is only happening with a single customer.In my AcceptMessage code, I make use of using statements:

```
TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
using (TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar))
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
```

I do not reference the listener after creating the client. In this code, I allow for multi-buffer messages, but I don't think anything in there is causing the issue.

My question is, why is BeginAcceptTcpClient not connecting, and is there anything that I can do to detect this and have it try again if needed?

Comment: Can you make this into a complete sample that we (and you) can use to reproduce the issue? Important details are missing, like how was the `server` object created, initialized and modified before and after the `server.BeginAcceptTcpClient` call. What else happens to `tcpClientConnected`. You haven't even put their type information. I don't want to guess that it is a `ManualResetEvent`

Comment: @Vikhram - Thank you for looking at this. Sorry I didn't have enough information; I was trying to put only what was needed. You are correct that I should have added the constructor. I don't think I need more in the AcceptMessage portion, which is hundreds of lines, but I can add this if it is helpful.

Comment: Why are you using `BeginAcceptTcpClient` if you are simply going to wait on a `ManualResetEvent`? Why not just use `AcceptTcpClient`?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that is wrong, at least in the provided code. If I were you, I would use the synchronous `Accept` call since you are sequentializing your calls, anyways.